# show that a formula belongs to theory of strict linear order

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I'm studying for my exam and I've been stuck on this problem for hours, I'd appreciate any help.

We have the following signature F = ∅ and  P = {$<^{(2)},=^{(2)}$} and we define the axiomatization $ A_{slo} $ that contains the following formulas :

$ ∀x. ¬(x < x) $

$∀x∀y∀z. (x < y∧y < z) ⇒ x < z $

$∀x∀y∀z. (x = y∧x < z) ⇒y < z$

$∀x∀y∀z. (x = y∧z < x) ⇒z < y$

$∀x∀y.x < y∨x = y∨y < x$

The interpretation I of domain $D_I ={a,b,c} $ where:

$<^I$ ={$(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)$}
$ =^I$ = {$(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$}

is a model of $A_{slo}$

Show that the formula below belongs to this theory ($\varphi \in Th(A_{slo}) $)

$\varphi = \forall x \exists y.(\neg(y<x) \Rightarrow \forall z.(x<z\ \lor \ x = z))$

I read that if $T\vDash \varphi$ then $\varphi \in T $, but I don't know how to prove it in this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Formula $\varphi$ is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication): $∀x \ (∀y¬(y<x) \to ∀z(x<z \lor x=z))$, i.e to:

> $∀x \ (∃y(y<x) \lor ∀z(x<z \lor x=z))$.

Your model is: $a < b < c$.

The formula says: for every element $x$, either $x$ is bigger than something, and this is true of $b$ and $c$, or it is less-or-equal than every element, and this is true of $a$.

Thus: $I \vDash \varphi$.

---

Having said that, we may consider that the above equivalent formulation of $\varphi$ is also eqyuivalent to :

> $∀x ∀z ∃y \ (y<x \lor x<z \lor x=z)$

which is "trichotomy in disguise".

Comment: Now wait, that argument is valid only if we know that $A_{slo}$ is complete. Unless we assume completeness, we need to check that *every* model of $A_{slo}$ satisfies $\varphi$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche - agreed... I've written **only** $I \vDash \varphi$. It is not very clear what is the role of $I$ in the question.

Comment: Indeed $I$ adds nothing but confusion!

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by Mauro Allegranza, $\varphi$ is equivalent to 
$\psi := \forall x \ (\exists y (y < x) \vee \forall z( x < z \vee x=z))$

Let's show that $A_{slo} \models \psi$. Let $M \models A_{slo}$ and $x \in D_M$.
If there is $y \in D_M$ such that $y < x$ then clearly $M \models \psi$.
If there is no such $y$ then by the 5th axiom of $A_{slo}$, this means that any $y \in D_M$ satisfies $x < y \vee x = y$. Of course the name $y$ is of no importance and we might as well rename $y$ to $z$ : we have $x < z \vee x = z$ for all $z$. qed

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation, but why don't you use $I $ and
$D_I$ instead of $M$ ?

Comment: @totoroji It's just a name. $M$ stands for "model". Besides, the name $I$ was already used for a specific model.